# Server Upload Code on time compaire Problem

Tags: c#, localhost

```
if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours < Convert.ToDateTime("22:00:00").TimeOfDay.Hours)                          
{

}
```

when I'm testing on localhost. it's working, but when I upload changes to the server. it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[Please try to improve your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

But my guess is you're struggling with [timezones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones) and time in general.

Time settings might be different on your server that's why it doesn't work.

Also use this code to compare current hour of the day:

```
if(DateTime.Now.Hour > 8) {
   Console.WriteLine("Good morning!");
} else {
   Console.WriteLine("Still working overtime?");
}
```

Comment: my code on godaddy server. i am doing today date skip after 8pm in dropdown..

Comment: TimeZoneInfo India_Standard_Time = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
                    DateTime dateTime_Indian = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, India_Standard_Time);